# FFMPEG - Convert a video to a timelapse

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, actionscript-3

I'm using ffmpeg in flash builder (Action script 3) to convert a video to a time lapse of the video. I've worked out how to use setpts to do this, but the resulting output file is the same length as the input (with just the last frame displayed after the time lapse), I want the duration to be changed based on the settings passed to ffmpeg.

I'm trying the below through the command line first:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v "setpts=0.5*PTS" output.mp4
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Problem solved. I wasn't removing the audio, so presumably it was playing the, near empty, audio file for the full time of the video.

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v "setpts=0.5*PTS" -an output.mp4`

`-an`  removes the audio from the video.

Answer (score 7):

Some more details here on speeding up audio. You can do up to 2x, but you can trick it to speed up even more ([source](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video)):

**Speeding up/slowing down audio**

You can speed up or slow down *audio* with the atempo audio filter. To double the speed of audio:

`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter:a "atempo=2.0" -vn output.mkv`

The atempo filter is limited to using values between 0.5 and 2.0 (so it can slow it down to no less than half the original speed, and speed up to no more than double the input). If you need to, you can get around this limitation by stringing multiple atempo filters together. The following with quadruple the audio speed:

`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter:a "atempo=2.0,atempo=2.0" -vn output.mkv`

Using a complex filtergraph, you can speed up video and audio at the same time:

`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.5*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=2.0[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mkv`